# Is memory allocated with new ever automatically freed?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I'm 99% certain the answer to this is a blinding **no**. Please validate my proposition that the following code will produce a memory leak.

```
Data &getData()
{
    Data *i = new Data();
    return *i;
}

void exampleFunc()
{
    Data d1 = getData();
    Data d2;

    /* d1 is not deallocated because it is on the heap, and d2 is
     * because it is on the stack. */
}
```

Please note that this is an oversimplified example, so clearly you wouldn't actually use the above code... So no need to point this out thanks.

#### Update 1:

To add to this, what if I assign the pointer to a reference? In this case, I assume that the data is not copied...

```
Data &getData()
{
    Data *i = new Data();
    return *i;
}

void exampleFunc()
{
    // Does copying occur here?
    Data &d1 = getData();

    // Does this deallocate the memory assigned to the pointer?
    delete &d;
}
```

#### Update 2:

I guess to answer my own question (in update 1) the following code proves that assigning a reference to a reference does not cause a copy...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Data
{
public:
    string mName;

    Data(const string &name) : mName(name)
    { cout << mName << " default ctor" << endl; }

    Data(const Data& other)
    {
        mName = other.mName + " (copy)";
        cout << mName << " copy ctor" << endl;
    }

    ~Data()
    { cout << mName << " dtor" << endl; }

    static Data &getData(const string &name)
    {
        Data *d = new Data(name);
        return *d;
    }
};

int main()
{
    cout << "d1..." << endl;
    Data d1 = Data::getData("d1");

    cout << "d2..." << endl;
    Data d2("d2");

    cout << "d3..." << endl;
    Data &d3 = Data::getData("d3");

    cout << "return..."  << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Yields the following result...

```
d1...
d1 default ctor
d1 (copy) copy ctor
d2...
d2 default ctor
d3...
d3 default ctor
return...
d2 dtor
d1 (copy) dtor
```

Thanks to Eric Melski for [a great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765971/is-memory-allocated-with-new-ever-automatically-freed/766002#766002) (my code in update 2 is a modified copy of his exmaple code).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Actually both `d1` and `d2` will be deallocated, because they are both on the stack.  What is not deallocated is the `Data` object you allocated in your `getData()` function.  You can see this a little more clearly if you flesh out your `Data` class with instrumentation in the constructors and destructor.  For example:

```
class Data {
public:
    Data() { cout << "Data default ctor" << endl; }
    Data(const Data& other) { cout << "Data copy ctor" << endl; }
    ~Data() { cout << "Data dtor" << endl; }

    static Data& getData()
    {
        Data *i = new Data();
        return *i;
    }
};
```

Note that I have explicitly declared the copy constructor for `Data`.  In your example you are implicitly calling that constructor when you do `Data d1 = getData();`, and I suspect this is where your confusion is coming from.  Now if I run this simple program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Data d1 = Data::getData();
    Data d2;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
Data default ctor
Data copy ctor
Data default ctor
Data dtor
Data dtor
```

Line-by-line, here's what you're seeing:

1. The default constructor is invoked when you allocate a new `Data` in `getData()`.
2. The copy constructor is invoked to create `d1` from the dynamically allocated `Data` you just made.
3. The default constructor is invoked to create `d2`.
4. The destructor is invoked for `d2` when it goes out of scope at the end of `main()`.
5. The destructor is invoked for `d1` when it goes out of scope at the end of `main()`.

Note that there are three constructor calls, but only two destructor calls -- indicating that you have leaked exactly one `Data` object.

Answer (score 8):

`d1` is a stack object, copy-constructed from the reference returned from `getData()`. `d1` is freed, but the object created in `getData()` is leaked.

Comment: When you say copy-constructed. What happens if there is no constructor on Data that takes Data? Does a deep copy occur?

Comment: No, a shallow copy occurs. i.e., any references and pointers in the object will point to the same objects as the original. _However_, the original object (as created in getData()) is still leaked, in this case.

Answer (score 3):

`d1` and `d2` are both stack object so will be destroyed at the end of their scope, the problem is that `getData()` creates a new heap object which is never deleted. `d1` is copy-initialized from a reference to this heap object and `d1` itself will be correctly destroyed at the end of `exampleFunc`, but the heap object generated in each call to `getData()` will not be deleted.

With the signature that `getData()` has it is possible to delete this object, but returning a reference to something that needs deleted is not an idiomatic interface.

Works, but is not a good interface:

```
Data& d = getData();
delete &d;
```

Answer (score 3):

The only time when you'll regain your memory is when the OS reclaims it automatically upon program termination. During your program execution what you posted will cause a memory leak as C++ doesn't have a built-in garbage collector and requires manual memory management for heap allocated objects.

Answer (score 1):

That is typical "way of thining" of Java/C# programmers.

In C++ you may actually use value types much more than you think:

```
Data getData()
{
    Data i;
    return i;
}

void exampleFunc()
{
    Data d1 = getData();
    /* d1 is constructed here and destroyed */
    Data d2;

}
```

If you want to return pointer, for example when you have some derived class that just use smart pointer like `auto_ptr` that allows movement of ownership:

```
auto_ptr<Data> getData()
{
    auto_ptr<Data> i(new Data());
    return i;
}

void exampleFunc()
{
    auto_ptr<Data> d1 = getData();
    /* now d1 is destroyed when goes out of scope */
    Data d2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in this. You have to explicitly deallocate memory using delete or delete[].

Answer (score 0):

To be accurate, the answer of your question is yes.

In this code:

```
int main()
{
Data* d = new Data();
return 0;   //end of execution
}
```

the data pointed-to by **d** is automatically freed by the operating system when the execution ends.

In other words, all the data which got allocated by program that finished executing but didn't get de-allocated by it (the program), will get de-allocated by the OS after (not during) the execution.